# Issue parsing namespaces using PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

I have this xml content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:searchResult total="1" xmlns:ns5="ers.ise.cisco.com" xmlns:ers-v2="ers-v2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns3="v2.ers.ise.cisco.com">
<ns3:resources>
<ns5:resource id="42e98860-cb88-11e5-9b0c-000c29c658fa" name="11:22:33:44:55:66">
<link rel="self" href="https://1.2.3.4:9060/ers/config/endpoint/42e98860-cb88-11e5-9b0c-000c29c658fa" type="application/xml"/>
</ns5:resource>
</ns3:resources>
</ns3:searchResult>
```

i need to get the value of the ns5:resource id value (42e98860-cb88-11e5-9b0c-000c29c658fa), but the use of namespaces in every node has me confused, i tried using the $xml->children('ns5',true)->resource->id and everything i try just gives me empty simplexml objects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question acccording to the help center

Comment: something specific i did wrong?

Comment: It's helpful if you include the code that you're trying (even if it doesn't work) to use to give us context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) expression:

> $elements =
>   $xml->xpath('/ns3:searchResult/ns3:resources/ns5:resource');

xpath will return an array and you can take the first item from that array. That item is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and you can get your id from its [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:searchResult total="1" xmlns:ns5="ers.ise.cisco.com" xmlns:ers-v2="ers-v2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns3="v2.ers.ise.cisco.com">
<ns3:resources>
<ns5:resource id="42e98860-cb88-11e5-9b0c-000c29c658fa" name="11:22:33:44:55:66">
<link rel="self" href="https://1.2.3.4:9060/ers/config/endpoint/42e98860-cb88-11e5-9b0c-000c29c658fa" type="application/xml"/>
</ns5:resource>
</ns3:resources>
</ns3:searchResult>
SOURCE;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$elements = $xml->xpath('/ns3:searchResult/ns3:resources/ns5:resource');
$element = $elements[0];
echo $element->attributes()->id->__toString();
```

Will result in:

> 42e98860-cb88-11e5-9b0c-000c29c658fa